# print lines between two patterns only when second pattern last column satisfy condition

Tags: regex, sed, awk

File is like below:

```
#########################################
some text 

some text

........

/pattern1/ some text here also in this line

some more text

some more text

/pattern2/ some text last_column/file


some text 

some text

.........

/pattern1/

some text

.....

.....

/pattern2/ some text last_column/filed

###########################################
```

NOTE:

1. Last_column/field is always a numeric value.
2. Both the patterns pattern1, pattern2 & some lines between the patterns will be present for sure.

could anyone please help me out?
I need the following outputs

1. I need to print all the lines between pattern1 and pattern2
2. I need to print the lines between pattern1 and pattern2 only when last column/field in pattern2 matching line is greater than 10, I dont want to print lines between these patterns if conditions not satisfies. i.e., last column/field of pattern2 matching line is lessser than 10.

awk , sed, grep anything is fine.

Comment: Post some ACTUAL sample input and expected output, not just a file showing the layout of the input.

Answer (score 1):

The first is trivial:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' input-file
```

For the second, I would do:

```
tac input-file | 
awk '/pattern2/ && $NF > 10 { p=1} p; /pattern1/{p=0}' |
tac
```

If you do not have access to `tac` (which merely reverses lines of input), you could do:

```
awk '/pattern1/{p=1}
p{ b = sprintf( "%s%s\n", b, $0 )}
/pattern2/ { if( $NF > 10 && p ) printf "%s", b; b=""; p=0 }' input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both with some fairly painless regular expressions with `grep`.

*These examples will print to `stdout`*

**1:** `grep -Pzo '(?s)(?<=/pattern1/).*?(?=/pattern2/)' file`

**2:** `grep -Pzo '(?s)(?<=/pattern1/).*?(?=/pattern2/.*?[1-9][0-9]+)' file`

### Explanation

**`grep` flags:**

```
-P              --perl-regexp (extended regex functionality)
-z              ignore newlines (`\n`) in input
-o              print only the matched part
```

**Regular expression:**

```
(?s)            #PCRE_DOTALL (. matches any character)
(?<=            #Positive look-behind (match this pattern, but don't include in the output)
    /pattern1/  
)    
.*?             #Find 0 or more of . (any character) in "non-greedy" mode
(?=             #Positive look-ahead (match this pattern, but don't include in the output)
    /pattern2/
    .*?         #Find 0 or more of . (any character) in "non-greedy" mode
    [1-9][0-9]+ #Match a number greater than 10 (which would be comprised of 
                #   one digit 1-9 followed by any number of digits 0-9)
)
```

Comment: Gr8, -z option is useful in grep.